# EditText AfterTextChanged Issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to create a simple time calculator app using two EditText fields. The code below is just a normal calculator that adds up two numbers that I whipped up to test the text changed listener. For some reason, every time I run this application and input a number into either EditText fields, it just crashes and asks if I want to restart the app. I just want it to update the total every time the user finishes entering a number instead of having to press a button. Can somebody help me find the error? I have initialized the first few variables outside of the onCreate method.

Log Error:

```
  07-03 21:06:45.499 2397-2397/com.example.thesoulreaper.swimmingcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.thesoulreaper.swimmingcalculator, PID: 2397
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:459)
        at com.example.thesoulreaper.swimmingcalculator.OneHundredCalculatorActivity$3.afterTextChanged(OneHundredCalculatorActivity.java:103)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8202)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10381)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1218)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:579)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:230)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:229)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:251)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:91)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

My code:

```
    fiftyEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FiftyEditText);
    hundredEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HundredEditText);
    totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);

    fiftyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                int total = Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString());
                totalTextView.setText(total);
            } else if(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                totalTextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()));
            } else if(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                totalTextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()));
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                totalTextView.setText(0);
            }
        }
    });

    hundredEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                int total = Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString());
                totalTextView.setText(total);
            } else if(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                totalTextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()));
            } else if(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                totalTextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()));
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0 && Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                totalTextView.setText(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the log error?

Comment: There is no error it just stops working

Comment: There has to be a logcat message...

Comment: I've added the log errors

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because you are trying to convert empty string to integer so add a check if the string is not empty

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    int hundredEditTextValue =  hundredEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(hundredEditText.getText().toString());
    int fiftyEditTextValue =  fiftyEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(fiftyEditText.getText().toString());

    if(hundredEditTextValue > 0 && fiftyEditTextValue > 0) {
        int total = hundredEditTextValue + fiftyEditTextValue;
        totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    } else if(hundredEditTextValue <= 0 && fiftyEditTextValue > 0) {
        totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(fiftyEditTextValue));
    } else if(hundredEditTextValue > 0 && fiftyEditTextValue <= 0) {
        totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(hundredEditTextValue));
    } else if (hundredEditTextValue <= 0 && fiftyEditTextValue <= 0) {
        totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    }
}
```

and just to make your edittext accepts only numbers add this in your xml

**android:inputType="number"**

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   .
   .
   android:inputType="number" />
```